# Nullreference exception when the model is not null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Today i faced strange exception. I have two tables in my DB, that have some linked columns. According to my app's logic i have to make an update on select and send updated list to my view. So, I act like this:

```
return View(repo.Enrollee.ToList().Select(p => {
               p.SpecialtyCode =  repo.EnrolleePlaces.FirstOrDefault(t => 
               t.SpecialtyCode == p.SpecialtyCode).Specialty; 
               return p; 
               }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Update));
```

When I make `foreach` on `Model` everything is Ok, but when I try to count model's items, using `@Model.Count()`, I get the `Nullreference`. I'm getting `Nullreference` even when I copy my `foreach` just under the first one. Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: One of your objects is clearly `null`.  Have you stepped through your debugger yet?

Comment: You're going to struggle debugging this when it's all one line of code. Break it apart.

Comment: could be old code somewhere cached. try Build > Clean Solution and Build > REBUILD. what happens now? And as @MichaelPerrenoud suggested - break the code into smaller managable chunks and easier reading.

Comment: Yeah, all the fields are not null. This was my first idea, but it seems that that is not a reason

Comment: another +1 for breaking it up. You'll maintain your sanity if you pass a variable like `return View(enrollees);` and break it down into 2 or 3 variables where needed. Also check for `null` where required.

Comment: model might not be null, but  because of the nature of expressions, could the `EnrolleePlaces` be null?, or possibly the `Specialty`?... not sure because it's all strung together.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell, all the fields are filled, I've got _correct_ `List` from the lambda expression, the first `foreach` _WORKS_ perfectly, but its copy(!!), located just under the first one, throws the exception.

WTF?)

Comment: you haven't posted the Razor code that you're consuming the model with. Can you update to show your Razor foreach?

Comment: without seeing everything including the razor code and even a stack trace, I'm "assuming" that one of the non nullable properties within the model are throwing.

Answer (score 3):

**Even if you are sure your variables are not null:**

If you are using `FirstOrDefault`, the returned value may be null, and therefore you must check it before accessing `.Specialty`:

```
p.SpecialtyCode =  repo.EnrolleePlaces.FirstOrDefault(t => 
t.SpecialtyCode == p.SpecialtyCode).Specialty;
```

You may use the following:

```
var someVar = repo.EnrolleePlaces.FirstOrDefault(t => t.SpecialtyCode == p.SpecialtyCode);
p.SpecialtyCode =  someVar == null? null : someVar.Specialty;
```

Comment: Mb you're right, i'll check it. But one thing confused me: when i make breakpoint in my view, the Model is totally right

Comment: it's true. Expressions (as I've recently discovered) are a pain, and you can't break on the return AND step into the expression... I had to write my own `ExpressionVisitor` a couple of weeks back, and holy sh*t.

Comment: @JohnH - agreed, do whatever you like, just be careful :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AlbinSunnanbo and his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666979/why-does-linq-query-throw-an-exception-when-i-attempt-to-get-a-count-of-a-type). I've got what i need. Just executed my query by calling another `ToList()`...

So, that's the answer:

```
return View(repo.Enrollee.ToList().Select(p => {
               p.SpecialtyCode =  repo.EnrolleePlaces.FirstOrDefault(t => 
               t.SpecialtyCode == p.SpecialtyCode).Specialty; 
               return p; 
               }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Update).ToList());
```